# I got an answer but the system rated my answer below 60%

Tags: python

I was given a task to "Create a function with two parameters a and b. The function calculates the following expression:  (12 * a + 25 * b) / (1 + a**(2**b)) and returns a result of the expression rounded up to the second decimal place.

but after writing my code I got a grade below 60%. I don't know what is wrong with my code

Here is my code:

```
a = 4
b = 5
result = (12 * a + 25 * b) / (1 + a ** (2 ** b))
print(result)
print("The value is: ", 9.378348791999613e-18)
print("The value rounded to 2 decimal place: ", round(9.378348791999613e-18, 2))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Have you completed a Python tutorial? Cause you should do that first. This site isn't built to teach the language basics (or programming in general for that matter). The reason I say that is because there's no function in your code like the assignment asks for, and functions are a very basic thing.

Answer (score 0):

Due to you need to use a function but your code not using function

Ex:

```
def sum(var_one, var_two):
    result = (12 * var_one + 25 * var_two) / (1 + var_one ** (2 ** var_two))
    print("The value is: ", result)
    print("The value rounded to 2 decimal place: {:.2f}".format(round(result, 2)))

sum(4, 5)
```